# Is it possible to export a Xamarin application and test it on an actual IPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I want to know if it is possible to build a Xamarin app and test it on an actual iPhone (physical device) without having to pay Apple developer fees. I am a student who just wants to learn and try to make a simple app to test it on an actual iPhone device.

Comment: No, you can't, you need an Apple developer license to try it on the real devices.

Comment: Actually you can now. I don't know how it works with Xamarin specifically, but you can now deploy apps to your device with only an Apple ID, no need to pay the $100/yr fee.

Comment: How would you deploy the app normally? Is there a good tutorial online for doing this for newbies? Would you need to use Xcode for this only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You need an Apple Developer account to do this, but as of mid 2015 Apple no longer charges for this.  You only need a paid membership for distributing apps in the Apple App store.